# how to find height and width of image for FileField Django

Tags: python, django, image, models, filefield

How to find height and width of image if our model is defined as follow

```
class MModel:
 document = FileField()
 format_type = CharField()
```

and image is saved in document then how we can find height and width of a document if it is image ?

Comment: You can change it to an `ImageField` and use `width_field` and `height_field` arguments.

Comment: did you mean ImageField(MModel.objects.all()[0]).height ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the files will always be images, change `FileField` to [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#imagefield), like this:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
  height = models.IntegerField()
  width = models.IntegerField()
  document = models.ImageField(height_field='height', width_field='width')
```

Otherwise, you'll have to manually calculate the image width and height:

```
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

obj = MModel.objects.get(pk=1)
width, height = get_image_dimensions(obj.document.file)
```